# Wrap text to width of browser or specified width, whichever is less

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How can I wrap the text displayed in the browser to **either** the width of the browser or a specified width, whichever is less?

I have been putting text inside `<table width='850'>` to wrap at a specific point, so if the user maximizes their browser on a gigantic monitor a whole paragraph doesn't fit in a single line.  But when the user makes the browser super narrow, the above method causes text to carry over the edge of the viewable area.  Not what I want exactly.

So, I'm looking for a better approach.

Oh, maybe I should add that my pages are extremely simple.  There aren't banners up and down the left or right sides of them.  Just text and images occupy the space from the left border of the browser to the right.  Boring stuff.

**EDIT** - I accepted an answer, but I did find an issue (and a solution that seems to work) with the accepted answer when used with Internet Explorer.  I spent half an hour trying to get max-width to work, but just couldn't. Every other style property worked fine though. Then I discovered this http://svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie which said I had to use the following for max-width to work in IE, and it did: p { width:expression(400 + "px"); }.  I don't understand why the fiddle example worked with max-width on IE, but not my page. Maybe it's cuz I include my css in my html page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `max-width` property in your css.

That way, the page will expand until a certain point and then no more.

Example:

```
.mainDiv{
    max-width:700px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pa5JG/

More info on `max-width`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Is there a correlation between the width attribute of the table tag and the max-width property?  For example, when I control the width with tables, I always like to use 850 as a value.  Would a max-width of 850px be the same?

Comment: Not entirely, @JohnFitzpatrick. With the `table width`, it will always be that width no matter what the size of the screen.  With `max-width`, the element will expand and contract but not more than the max.  That said, `max-width:850px` should give you what you need.

Comment: Almost, the width attribute equates somewhat to css width in px, but you should not use those attributes in the HTML anymore. Use CSS

Comment: @Stein, yes I know.  I have a big book on CSS that I've been meaning to read for almost two years.  Other things keep getting in the way.  You may be horrified to hear I even still use the `<font>` tag.  But never without a pang of guilt.

Comment: I spent half an hour trying to get max-width to work, but just couldn't. Every other style property worked fine though. Then I discovered this http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/ which said I had to use the following for max-width to work in IE, and it did: `p { width:expression(400 + "px"); }`. Has any of you heard about this?  (And I don't understand why the fiddle example worked with max-width on IE, but not my page.  Maybe it's cuz I include my css in my html page?)

Comment: Oh my gosh, it gets worse! In IE using `width:expression(400 + "px")` will not cause the max width to reduce to the browser width if the browser width is less than the specified amount! You have to do THIS to get that effect: `width:expression((document.body.clientWidth > 400)? "400px" : "auto")` for that. I found that here: http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/05/19/css-hackz-series-minimum-width-maximum-width-for-internet-explorer-6/. (Correct me please if I'm wrong!)

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick You original question is a solid on, and I didn't catch the double negative on the guilt, but even still... `<font>` elements? really?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `max-width`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/rB9mT/).